# SpringBatch Teradata DatabaseType support

Tags: java, spring-batch, teradata

I'm using SpringBatch 5 with Teradata db , I tried to create a job repository to add a datasource but i get an exception about org.springframework.batch.support.DatabaseType :

```
Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.batch.core.repository.JobRepository]: Factory method 'jobRepository' threw exception with message: No enum constant org.springframework.batch.support.DatabaseType.TERADATA
```

the JobRepository :

```
 @Bean
public JobRepository jobRepository(@Qualifier("dataSource") DataSource dataSource,
                                   PlatformTransactionManager transactionManager) throws Exception {
    JobRepositoryFactoryBean jobRepositoryFactoryBean = new JobRepositoryFactoryBean();
    jobRepositoryFactoryBean.setDataSource(dataSource);
    jobRepositoryFactoryBean.setTransactionManager(transactionManager);
    jobRepositoryFactoryBean.setIsolationLevelForCreate("ISOLATION_SERIALIZABLE");
    jobRepositoryFactoryBean.setDatabaseType("TERADATA");
    jobRepositoryFactoryBean.setIncrementerFactory(new DefaultDataFieldMaxValueIncrementerFactory(dataSource));
    return jobRepositoryFactoryBean.getObject();
}
```

Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score -1):

Teradata is not officially supported in Spring Batch. Since you have defined a teradata datasource, you can omit setting the `DatabaseType` on the `JobRepositoryFactoryBean`, which will try to auto-detect the type from the datasource's metadata.

Please refer to [Non-standard Database Types in a Repository](https://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/docs/current/reference/html/job.html#nonStandardDatabaseTypesInRepository) for more details.

Comment: You can not omit DatabaseType  , code throw erro like "threw exception with message: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: DatabaseType not found for product name:" 

cause : org.springframework.batch.support.DatabaseType have a methode fromProductName(String productName) that throw Exception : 

   throw new IllegalArgumentException("DatabaseType not found for product name: [" + productName + "]"); whene Type not in enum's types

Refer to : https://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/docs/current/api/org/springframework/batch/support/DatabaseType.html

Comment: @Yaz, you can omit the database type, see https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-batch/blob/f64d6e88a5cd243b49753771ce794b9bd524784e/spring-batch-core/src/main/java/org/springframework/batch/core/repository/support/JobRepositoryFactoryBean.java#L271-L276. In which case, the type will be introspected from the datasource's metadata as mentioned in the answer.